# Trouble binding a variadic lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a function that will bind a variadic lambda factory method to a function which takes no parameters. I'm not sure if the VC support(using VS2012 with the Nov. 2012 CTP) isn't fully there or if (more likely) I'm doing it wrong. I haven't worked much with variadic templates, so any help would be appreciated.

```
template <typename T, typename...Args>
std::function<T*()> MakeFactoryMethod(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind([](Args&&... args2)
        {
            return new T(std::forward<Args>(args2)...);
        },
        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

...

auto test = MakeFactoryMethod<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor>(5);
```

I receive a long set of errors from the compiler. It looks like the VC standard library is not yet making use of variadic templates itself.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(431): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Do_call_ret<false,_Ret,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,std::tuple<int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,std::tuple<std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>::type' to 'SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(239) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,_Ty,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Rx=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(239) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,_Ty,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Rx=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(239) : while compiling class template member function 'SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Do_call(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>  ,            _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(514) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>  ,            _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\configurabletestserver\application.cpp(121) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *(void)>::function<std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,_Ty,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\configurabletestserver\application.cpp(121) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *(void)>::function<std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,_Ty,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_eabc5b7f0a2cea764c71ce16901cde81>,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\configurabletestserver\application.cpp(139) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor *(void)> MakeFactoryMethod<SomeClassWithSingleIntConstructor,int>(int &&)' being compiled
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I think the problem is that you lambda is void, but returns pointer

Comment: Do note that even given a conforming implementation, you'd need the lambda to accept `Args&...`, not `Args&&`. The bound arguments of an `std::bind` arguments are always forwarded as lvalues. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c0791276414f1ce68d1878e55eb9f285-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like you're trying to overcomplicate it. Why capture them by RHR and then pass them as a perfect forward - which means you'll capture any temporaries as temporary - when you are going to make a functor out of it? That means you'd have to pass in a copy or such into each new call to ensure the objects still exist.

```
template <typename T, typename...Args>
std::function<T*()> MakeFactoryMethod(Args&&... args)
{
    return [=]()
        {
            return new T(args...);
        }
}
```

When you do have to make a copy, just make a copy in the lambda creation and be done with it.

The error message is very confusing but to me it seems like making a lambda out of right-hand-references is wrong by design, so I'm not too fussed about the error messages.

Comment: Good point. For this use case I was doing a lot of unnecessary work. I used this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda returns  `void`

should be

```
template <typename T, typename...Args>
std::function<T*()> MakeFactoryMethod(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind([](Args&&... args2) -> T*
        {
            return new T(std::forward<Args>(args2)...);
        },
        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: No, a single statement lets the lambda infer the return type.

Comment: @Xeo `_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<false,void,MakeFactoryMethod::<lambda_e...` but due to that bind assumes that argument is `void`-returning function. I'm not familiar with `std::bind`, but maybe `boost::bind<T*>` analogue will help